# How to remove duplicate elements from this list, without using Set?

Tags: java

```
class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Emp> l=new ArrayList<Emp>();
        l.add(new Emp(1,23000,"ram");
        l.add(new Emp(2,24000,"aam");
        l.add(new Emp(1,23000,"ram");
    }
}

class Emp {
    int id, salary, name;

    Emp(int id, int salary,int name) {
        this.id=id;
        this.salary=salary;   
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Comment: no set? then map ? :-)

Comment: Simple nested loops will suffice .. a bit of care to avoid a CME, but not hard. I recommend creating a new array list as it makes the work a bit easier.

Comment: `int name` should be `String name` as per your constructor call

Comment: By the way, in this example, I see a list of 3 different employees. The first and the third are not equals without more code.

Comment: In addition to showing us what you have tried so far, you should note that a set would not work in this case because you have not overridden the `equals` test in `Emp`, and so two separate objects with the same values will be considered different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is to add `equals()` and `hashCode()` to your Emp class, like this (without constructor, getter and setter):

```
public class Emp {
  private int id;
  private int salary;
  private int name;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Emp)) {
      return false;
    }

    final Emp emp = (Emp) o;

    if (id != emp.id) {
      return false;
    }
    if (name != emp.name) {
      return false;
    }
    if (salary != emp.salary) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = id;
    result = 31 * result + salary;
    result = 31 * result + name;
    return result;
  }
}
```

And then you can write a method like:

```
public List<Emp> removeDuplicate(final List<Emp> items) {
    final List<Emp> result = new ArrayList<Emp>();
    final List<Emp> doublettes = new ArrayList<Emp>();
    for(final Emp item : items) {
        if (!doublettes.contains(item) {
            result.add(item);
            doublettes.add(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

By the way, do you really want an `int` for name? In your example you use a String and in the constructor int. If you want `String`you must modify `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: the datatype for name is String name;